How to make an EF Core query using Expression?
How to query a database with EF Core using Expression?
I'd like to build a dynamic query according to metadata, and query/edit data in a dynamic way, probably it could be with Expression. How could I do that?
Target:
db.Blogs.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.BlogId == 1);

Code?
var funcAsNoTracking = Expression.Call(dbSet.GetType().GetMethod("AsNoTracking")!);
var funcFirstOrDefault = Expression.Call(typeof(IQueryable<>).GetMethod("FirstOrDefault")!);
/* what to do next or else? */
//Code

Other code:
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new();
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}


Thanks for your answer @phuzi
After a nice weekend rest, I can focus on the implementation and figure it out myself, share it hoping help others.
The conclusion, EF core could make this, still I would like try another way witch like LINQ to SQL to build dynamic solution.
Note, this is just some demo code only show the purpose, the full code is large.
Part A: Metadata
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> AllDbSets
    {
        get
        {
            //TODO: setup with dynamic registration and cache
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { nameof(Blogs), Blogs }, { nameof(Posts), Posts } };
            return dic;
        }
    }
}

The newly added AllDbSets
Part B: Dynamic search model
internal class Query
{
    public Query(List<string> fileds, List<IFilter> filters)
    {
        this.Fileds = fileds;
        this.Filters = filters;
    }

    public List<string> Fileds { get; set; }
    public List<IFilter> Filters { get; set; }
}

internal interface IFilter
{

}

internal class EqualFilter : IFilter
{
    public EqualFilter(string field, object value)
    {
        this.Filed = field;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Filed { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}


Note: Just for this demo

Part C: Query Engine process with demo
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = new Query(new List<string> { "Blogs.BlogId", "Blogs.Url" }, new List<IFilter>() { new EqualFilter("Blogs.BlogId", 1) });

    var queryDBSetName = query.Fileds.Select(p => p.Split(".")[0]).Distinct().First();


    using BloggingContext db = new();
    {
        //Get DB set and basic metadata from ef core
        var set = db.AllDbSets[queryDBSetName];
        var setType = set.GetType();
        var entityType = setType.GenericTypeArguments.First();

        //AsNoTracking methodinfo
        var methodInfoAsNoTracking = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsNoTracking))!.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        //Build AsNoTracking expression
        var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(entityType), "source");
        var asNoTrackingExpression = Expression.Call(methodInfoAsNoTracking, sourceParam);

        //FirstOrDefault methodinfo
        var methodInfoFirstOrDefault = typeof(Queryable).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods.First(p => p.Name == nameof(Queryable.FirstOrDefault) && p.GetParameters().Length == 2 && p.GetParameters()[1].Name == "predicate")!.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

        //Build property predicate expression
        var propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty("BlogId")!;
        var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "p");
        var left = Expression.Property(param, propertyInfo);
        var right = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int));

        var predicateExpression = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        //Make lambda filter expression
        Expression filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(predicateExpression, param);

        //FirstOrDefault expression with filter
        var callFirstOrDefault = Expression.Call(methodInfoFirstOrDefault, Expression.Lambda(asNoTrackingExpression, sourceParam).Body, filterExpression);

        //Make the call of expression
        var result = Expression.Lambda(callFirstOrDefault, sourceParam).Compile().DynamicInvoke(set);
    }
}

The filter from query ignored, but does not matter for demo.

Again, it is just a test demo, lots of work to make it perfect.


Give to Caesar what is Caesars. IMHO don't try to use reflection with all those generics, instead write a generic method and only use reflection to call it. That way you can work with db.Set<T>(), IQueryable<T>, .AsNoTracking(), .FirstOrDefault() etc directly and only focus on building the Expression tree.

And even then you can probably solve your other problems without building the Expression tree manually. Just enforce that interface IKey { int Id { get; set; }}, class Blog : IKey and you can db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1); for any table.

@JeremyLakeman, as my understanding, the the generic type T is undetermined before the "Query" is submit, since requester will try query any entity and include dynamic subsequence. I would not like use a hard code to switch case all entity types, since the sample code just a little piece of the solution. the system is metadata driven,  and know nothing about the fixed types.

If you actually need to build expression trees, then go ahead and do that. But IMHO you should first attempt to avoid that.

We are supporting  .Where(), OrderBy() etc, we can't set up static solutions.

@JeremyLakeman, the mis-understanding is the target of the system, it's metadata driven&low code system, not a simple application, we could not avoid the dynamic and complicated things.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

From what you've stated I think you might be over-thinking the problem.
If it's as simple as you've stated then you could just do something like.
Expression<Func<Blog, bool>> selectorExpression = (p) => p.BlogId == 1;
var blogs = db.Blogs;
Blog? result = default;

if (useAsNoTracking) // Introduce some logic that sets this.
    blogs = blogs.AsNoTracking();

if (useFirstOrDefault) // Introduce some logic that sets this too.
    result = blogs.FirstOrDefault(selectorExpression);

Things get quite a bit more complicated if you're trying to dynamically build Expressions though and I have answered a similar question here c# use string parameter to define what property to filter by in List of objects

If you can avoid using reflection and building expression trees manually, then you should do that. I'm not saying that all problems could be solved that way, but most can. From your example;
public interface IKey {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Blog : IKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // etc
}

public T GetItem<T>(DbContext db, int id) where T : class, IKey
    => db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);

Of course supporting fully dynamic where clauses is an entirely separate problem. But there are other existing solutions for that, like Dynamic Linq. I wouldn't recommend trying to build your own solution to that.

many thanks to your demonstration, really happy we could talk deep into this section. In your code segment, I face real situation - A:"Blog"/"Post" defined by system admin, we could not have the generic T in code, all we know is we have a entity and named. B: The IKey is static, the system admin would like have GUID key or multiple PKs. What we know is the metadata description, no Entity/Type can be in code.

I would like use a dynamic entity type, key/values or runtime dynamic type, but it's totally another thing.

I would like look into "Dynamic Linq" to see what we can have.

For all guid keys, you should be able to reuse an interface like the above, even if you need to .Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("BlogId"). Calling GetItem<T> via .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke is still much simpler than performing each step of that function via reflection. At least for all the same key types. But if absolutely everything is dynamic, then entity framework is probably the wrong tool. If everything is metadata driven, you could just use SqlCommand / SqlDataReader directly.

yes, I am proving it's totally mistake using EF Core. we already have an AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) to SQL library, metadata->AST->SQL, executed by SqlCommand / SqlDataReader, dealing with DCL, DDL, DML and DQL. Of course, it's too far out of scope. thanks again for the conversation, I'll close this issue.
